# What is the recommended data type for Grade Calculations?

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

The grade calculation is 1.0 is the highest and 5.0 is the lowest grade. Only allows 1 decimal place. Can you tell me what is the best data type to be used?

Comment: if it be MSSQL Server or Oracle then It was easy, but in MYSQL I don't know exactly what's the best way for it. hope you'll find the answer, good luck

Comment: Um, DECIMAL(2,1) ???

Comment: it's not the all, for example in MSSQL Server: you can create a user defined data type + user defied rule + bind the column with defined datatype to the defined rule, if the RDBMS was MSSQL I'll write the full code in answer

Comment: @FarhangAmary so what should i use? is it integer? numeric? decimal? or float? i just want 1 decimal place thats all.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a classic usecase for [`decimal(2,1)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html).

You could also enforce the grade range by adding  a constraint (`CHECK (grade >= 1.0 and grade <= 5.0)`).